# Google Analytics timing event not sent

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

**Edit: Here was the code that was acutuallynot working**

(I had changed it to simplify the question)

```
<script>
    // save startTime at the begginning of the page
    var _startTime = new Date().getTime();
</script>
<!--
    ... page code here ...
-->
<script>
    //Google Analytics code
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    (function (w,d,$,ga,createFunction) {

        createFunction = function(timingVar) {
            return function() {
                var time = (new Date().getTime() - _startTime);

                if (time > 0) {
                    ga('send', 'timing', 'performance', timingVar, time, 'desktop');
                } //if

                if (console && console.log) console.log(timingVar +':'+ time);

            };
        };

        $(d).on('ready',createFunction('page ready'));
        $(w).on('load',createFunction('page load'));
    })(window,document,jQuery,ga);
</script>
```

Still not sure why this code is not working.

**Here is my Original Question  (code works)**

I'm trying to use [User Timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingTiming?hl=en) function of Google Analytics to track page load times under different scenarios.

I'm unable to get the timings command to be sent on page load.  Here is the code I am using to get this to happen.

```
<script>
    // save startTime at the begginning of the page
    var _startTime = new Date().getTime();
</script>
<!--
    ... page code here ...
-->
<script>
    //Google Analytics code
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    // track document ready even time
    $(document).on('ready',function() {
        var time = (new Date().getTime() - _startTime);

        if (time > 0) {
            ga('send', 'timing', 'performance', 'page ready', time, 'desktop');
        } //if

        console.log('page ready:'+ time);
    });

    // track window load time
    $(window).on('load',function() {
        var time = (new Date().getTime() - _startTime);

        if (time > 0) {
            ga('send', 'timing', 'performance', 'page load', time, 'desktop');
        } //if

        console.log('page load:'+ time);
    });


</script>
```

I'm testing this in Chrome and have the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) extension installed.

I look in the console and I see the pageview and timings "page ready" commands being sent, but the timings "page load" command is never sent.

Both `console.log()` show the events being fired, yet there is no data sent to Google Analytics for the timings "page load" command.

Here are other verifications I've done:

- The value of time is always an Integer.
- It doesn't matter if I only have the "page load" timings command

Here is the results I get when having only the pageview and timings page load event:
[image: Console Results]

Any ideas on what might be the reason the command is not sent on window's load event?

Comment: That looks correct to me. What is the debugger saying about the `ga('send', 'timing', ...)` commands? It should either say success or tell you what failed.

Comment: Did you wait 24 hours for the data to show up in the standard reports?

Comment: @PhilipWalton I've edtited the question to show what I get from the debugger.  The command is not fired at all with no message saying it failed, weird huh?

Comment: @DaImTo after 24hrs I see some data in reports, but I have 14 000 events of the document ready and 900 events of the page load (Which should equal the same amount).  So the command seems to be firing for some users, but I can't get to see any data sent from my browser.  I have since removed the document ready command and now I'm only left  with the page load one.  I'll report the result tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something must be different about the code you're actually running and the code you've pasted on this page. Everything here looks fine to me, and if I run your exact code, it works.

You can take a look at this jsbin demo for proof. Notice how three hits are sent: 1 pageview and 2 timing hits.
http://jsbin.com/kafeduweme/edit?html,console

Comment: Ok I had a `(function (w,d,$,ga) { ... })(window,document,jQuery,ga)` around my code and it wasn't working.  I removed the wrapper function and both commands get sent (regardless of the siteSpeedSampleRate).  I will update the question to reflect this.  I had removed from my question to simplify the code, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

### Default sample rate is 1% for timing report

This is not a mistake. This is about default configuration of tracker itself. This functionality is limited by sampling and this feature has 1% sampling by default for timing tracking function. So there is very low posibility to see event in console.

### Solution

Set sample rate when initiating tracker:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 50});
```

### Documentation

**Field reference:**
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#siteSpeedSampleRate

**Feature description:**
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings

Comment: Ok I've tried with the new site sample rate of 50 and 100 and now I see a beacon sent to GA.  It doesn't seem to contain the category, var name, value and label in it though.  Here is the screen shot of what debugger show https://goo.gl/photos/u4AnnmeyuzwaPtXv7.  I will wait and see if the data is in the timings report.

Comment: This entire answer is incorrect. `siteSpeedSampleRate` has no affect on sending timing this. It only affects the site speed hits analytics.js automatically sends.

Comment: Would you be willing to update this answer? I burned a few days on this (because I had to revert to using normal events instead of timing events and rewrite my dashboards)